# Ubuntu 16.04 Upgrade Lowered My Monitor Resolution

Tags: display, display-resolution

I upgraded my 14.04 LTS machine to 16.04 LTS. My 27" Monoprice LCD monitor was running 2560x1440 @ 60Hz on 14.04, but now will only run at 1920x1080. The Displays app no longer has the 2560x1440 option in the dropdown. I'm running Intel graphics on VGA-1. I've tried adding the 2560x1440_60.00 mode via xrandr and the display locks up. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Were you running the same monitor over the same port, or did you switch it to VGA? It sounds like you are trying to drive a 1440p monitor over VGA, which is not possible.

Comment: I didn't change anything except the OS. 14.04 LTS drove the monitor at 2560x1440 through VGA-1, but after the 16.04 "upgrade" the res has changed to 1920x1080.  That's the highest res in the Displays dropdown. I tried switching to the DVI port, but the highest res it will drive is 1920x1080.  The DVI port is through the discreet (AMD 8750) card.